# Angular 4- Implementing a multi page form with dynamic form fields

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I was trying to implement a multi page form in Angular 4 which should be able to do the following:
1- Allow a user to navigate through different form pages.
2- Should have the ability to go back to previous page of a form and still be able to see the entries made by him.
3- Be able to dynamically add form fields such as more than one phone number, address etc.
 I was able to achieve the first two functionalities in my form by following the tutorial described at the below link:

https://www.cc28tech.com/angular-multi-step-wizard-part-1/

The third part however is the tricky one for me. I am not able to understand as to how to go forward achieving the same. I understand that I will have to use a form array for the same, but implementing the same in the code mentioned in the above link is tricky for me. If anyone can please guide me as to how to achieve the same, that would be a great help for me.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

formData.model.ts

```
export class FormData {
firstName: string = '';
lastName : string = '';
email: string = '';
work: string = '';
street: string = '';
city: string = '';
state: string = '';
zip: string = '';

clear() {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.email = '';
    this.work = '';
    this.street = '';
    this.city = '';
    this.state = '';
    this.zip = '';
   }
 }

 export class Personal {
firstName: string = '';
lastName : string = '';
email: string = '';
}

export class Address {
street: string = '';
city: string = '';
state: string = '';
zip: string = '';
}
```

formData.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormData, Personal, Address } from './formData.model';
import { WorkflowService }  from '../workflow/workflow.service';
import { STEPS } from '../workflow/workflow.model';

@Injectable()
  export class FormDataService {

   private formData: FormData = new FormData();
   private isPersonalFormValid: boolean = false;
   private isWorkFormValid: boolean = false;
   private isAddressFormValid: boolean = false; 

constructor(private workflowService: WorkflowService) { }

       getPersonal(): Personal {
    // Return the Personal data
       var personal: Personal = {
        firstName: this.formData.firstName,
        lastName: this.formData.lastName,
        email: this.formData.email
    };
    return personal;
  }

   setPersonal(data: Personal) {
    // Update the Personal data only when the Personal Form had been 
   validated successfully
    this.isPersonalFormValid = true;
    this.formData.firstName = data.firstName;
    this.formData.lastName = data.lastName;
    this.formData.email = data.email;
    // Validate Personal Step in Workflow
    this.workflowService.validateStep(STEPS.personal);
 }

   getWork() : string {
    // Return the work type
    return this.formData.work;
 }

  setWork(data: string) {
    // Update the work type only when the Work Form had been validated 
    successfully
    this.isWorkFormValid = true;
    this.formData.work = data;
    // Validate Work Step in Workflow
    this.workflowService.validateStep(STEPS.work);
}

    getAddress() : Address {
    // Return the Address data
        var address: Address = {
        street: this.formData.street,
        city: this.formData.city,
        state: this.formData.state,
        zip: this.formData.zip
    };
    return address;
}

  setAddress(data: Address) {
    // Update the Address data only when the Address Form had been validated 
    successfully
    this.isAddressFormValid = true;
    this.formData.street = data.street;
    this.formData.city = data.city;
    this.formData.state = data.state;
    this.formData.zip = data.zip;
    // Validate Address Step in Workflow
    this.workflowService.validateStep(STEPS.address);
}

getFormData(): FormData {
    // Return the entire Form Data
    return this.formData;
}

resetFormData(): FormData {
    // Reset the workflow
    this.workflowService.resetSteps();
    // Return the form data after all this.* members had been reset
    this.formData.clear();
    this.isPersonalFormValid = this.isWorkFormValid = 
    this.isAddressFormValid = false;
    return this.formData;
}

isFormValid() {
    // Return true if all forms had been validated successfully; otherwise, 
        return false
        return this.isPersonalFormValid &&
            this.isWorkFormValid && 
            this.isAddressFormValid;
    }
 }
```

workflow.model.ts

```
export const STEPS = {
personal: 'personal',
work: 'work',
address: 'address',
result: 'result'
  }
```

workflow-guard.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
CanActivate, Router,
ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
RouterStateSnapshot,
CanLoad, Route
} from '@angular/router';

  import { WorkflowService } from './workflow.service';

  @Injectable()
  export class WorkflowGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private workflowService: 
  WorkflowService { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
  boolean {
    let path: string = route.routeConfig.path;

    return this.verifyWorkFlow(path);
}

verifyWorkFlow(path) : boolean {
    console.log("Entered '" + path + "' path.");

    // If any of the previous steps is invalid, go back to the first invalid 
      step
    let firstPath = this.workflowService.getFirstInvalidStep(path);
    if (firstPath.length > 0) {
        console.log("Redirected to '" + firstPath + "' path which it is the 
    first invalid step.");
        let url = `/${firstPath}`;
        this.router.navigate([url]);
        return false;
    };

    return true;
 }
}
```

workflow.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { STEPS }   from './workflow.model';

@Injectable()
export class WorkflowService {
private workflow = [
    { step: STEPS.personal, valid: false },
    { step: STEPS.work, valid: false },
    { step: STEPS.address, valid: false },
    { step: STEPS.result, valid: false }
];

validateStep(step: string) {
    // If the state is found, set the valid field to true 
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.workflow.length && !found; i++) {
        if (this.workflow[i].step === step) {
            found = this.workflow[i].valid = true;
        }
    }
}

resetSteps() {
    // Reset all the steps in the Workflow to be invalid
    this.workflow.forEach(element => {
        element.valid = false;
    });
}

getFirstInvalidStep(step: string) : string {
    // If all the previous steps are validated, return blank
    // Otherwise, return the first invalid step
    var found = false;
    var valid = true;
    var redirectToStep = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < this.workflow.length && !found && valid; i++) {
        let item = this.workflow[i];
        if (item.step === step) {
            found = true;
            redirectToStep = '';
        }
        else {
            valid = item.valid;
            redirectToStep = item.step
        }
    }
    return redirectToStep;
  }
}
```

personal.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router }  from '@angular/router';
 import { Personal }   from '../data/formData.model';
 import { FormDataService } from '../data/formData.service';

 @Component({
selector: 'app-personal',
templateUrl: './personal.component.html'

})
export class PersonalComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Tell us about Yourself';
personal: Personal;
form: any;

constructor(private router: Router, private formDataService: 
FormDataService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.personal = this.formDataService.getPersonal();
  console.log('Personal feature loaded!');
   } 

save(form: any): boolean {
  if (!form.valid) {
      return false;
  }

  this.formDataService.setPersonal(this.personal);
  return true;
}

 goToNext(form: any) {
  if (this.save(form)) {
      // Navigate to the work page
      this.router.navigate(['vendorOnboarding/work']);
  }
}
 back()
 {

  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  } 
}
```

personal.component.html

```
<form #personalForm="ngForm" class="editForm" novalidate>
<div class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h4 class="head text-center">{{title}}</h4>
    <br/>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8'>
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="firstname">First 
                        Name</label>  
                        <input class="form-control input-md" 
                        #firstname="ngModel" required id="firstname" 
                       name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" 
                       [(ngModel)]="personal.firstName">

                        <div class="alert alert-danger" 
                        [hidden]="firstname.valid">First Name is 
                         required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last 
                         Name</label>  
                        <input class="form-control input-md" 
                         #lastname="ngModel" required id="lastname" 
                         name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" 
                         [(ngModel)]="personal.lastName">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" 
                        [hidden]="lastname.valid">Last Name is 
                         required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control input-md" #email="ngModel" 
                required pattern="^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$" id="email" 
                name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" 
                [(ngModel)]="personal.email">

                <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="email.valid">Email 
                 is required and must be valid</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-outline-rounded btn-info" 
                [disabled]="!personalForm.valid" 
                (click)="goToNext(personalForm)"> Next <span style="margin- 
                left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> 
           </button>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My only requirement is to allow a user to dynamically add form fields like multiple email addresses. what I am looking for is having a + and - button in my form that allows a user to add multiple email addresses. I was able to find multiple solutions for the same but however unable to replicate the same in the above code.

Please guide me as to how to achieve the same.

Thanks !

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: @Chellappan I have now updated the post, please have a look